# Trying to embed vlcj media player in a WindowsCanvas inside a JPanel

Tags: java, video, jpanel, vlcj

I'm trying to play a video using vlcj inside a JPanel but it doesn't work for me. The message exception I am getting is "java.lang.IllegalStateException: The video surface component must be displayable" which is the same problem as in [Keep getting an Error "Component must be displayable"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830567/keep-getting-an-error-component-must-be-displayable).

The code of the JPanel which contains the canvas and the vlcj player is this:

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;

import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.binding.LibVlc;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.MediaPlayerFactory;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.embedded.EmbeddedMediaPlayer;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.embedded.videosurface.CanvasVideoSurface;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.runtime.RuntimeUtil;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.runtime.windows.WindowsCanvas;

public class MyJPanel extends JPanel {
private EmbeddedMediaPlayer player;
private WindowsCanvas canvas;

public MyJPanel() {
    canvas = new WindowsCanvas();
    add(canvas);
    revalidate();
    repaint();

    canvas.setVisible(true);

    MediaPlayerFactory mediaPlayerFactory = new MediaPlayerFactory();
    player = mediaPlayerFactory.newEmbeddedMediaPlayer();

    CanvasVideoSurface videoSurface = mediaPlayerFactory.newVideoSurface(canvas);

    player.setVideoSurface(videoSurface);
    player.playMedia("v.avi");   // This sentence throws the exception.
}
}
```

MyJFrame extends JFrame and only contains the MyJPanel JPanel. I think it's not important at all.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class MyJFrame extends JFrame {
protected MyJPanel myJPanel;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                MyJFrame frame = new MyJFrame();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

public MyJFrame() {
    myJPanel = new myJPanel();
    add(myJPanel);
}   
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I could ask a dozen questions, but they would all be answered in 1 [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  Why not post an SSCCE?

Comment: O...K  Which of those 2 sources is the SSCCE?

Comment: @AndrewThompson The first one.

Comment: The 1st one has no main.  Combine the two into one source code ***as described by the SSCCE document.***  Continue wasting your time if you want, but please **stop** wasting mine.  :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're trying to play the media before the frame containing the canvas has been set to be visible. You'll need to put the `playMedia()` call in a separate method, and call it *after* the entire frame has been created and set as visible.

EDIT:

If you still want it to play straight off, just call the relevant method after you've created and made your frame visible:

```
MyJFrame frame = new MyJFrame();
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.startPlaying();
```

...obviously you'll need to define `startPlaying()` on MyJFrame, but then it should start playing straight off. you just need to set the frame visible first.

Comment: You can't imagine how much I appreciate all your help. Really thanks. I've created a JButton to start the playing. Although, I would prefer autoplaying. What's the reason? I don't understand why it doesn't run.

Comment: It works perfectly. Does the frame decide a different order to paint the components?

Comment: @honnix It's nothing to do with painting order, it's simply that the underlying libvlc library requires the canvas is made visible on the screen before it will play a video on it (that's a simplification, but the idea is the same.)

Comment: I have tried the same code and I have added `playMedia(url)` after `setVisible(true)` but when I execute my code, I get only the panel and no video is playing, whith no error in the console! see [my post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13440760/embedding-vlcj-in-jpanel)