# Display VLCJ player in Canvas

Tags: java, swing, canvas, vlcj

I try to put a VLCJ player inside a canvas. 
I have already read many subjects about it, but I still can't achieved what I would like to do.

Here is the code I use :

```
public class RaspberryControler extends JFrame 
{

    /*Have to declare it in order to use vlcj*/
    private EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent mediaPlayerComponent;
    private EmbeddedMediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    public RaspberryControler(String host){
       this.host = host;
       controler = new Controler(this);  
       initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents(){      
      setBasicParameters();
      createMainPanel();
      createControlPanel(); 
      createWebcamPanel(); 
      mainPanel.add(webcamPanel); 
      mainPanel.add(controlPanel); 
      setListeners();       

      /*Set the last parameters of the frame*/
      this.revalidate();
      this.repaint();
      this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);     
   }

   private void createMainPanel(){

       mainPanel = new JPanel();

       /*Set the Layout*/
       mainPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
       mainPanel.setVisible(true);

       /*Set the parameters*/ 
       this.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
   }

    private void createWebcamPanel(){       
      /*Get the VLC Libraries*/
    NativeLibrary.addSearchPath(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), "C:/VLC/VideoLAN/VLC");
    Native.loadLibrary(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), LibVlc.class);

    /*Create components*/
    liveStream = new JLabel("Live Stream"); 
    mediaPlayerComponent = new EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent(); 

    /*Set parameters of the components*/
    liveStream.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 30));
    liveStream.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

    /*Set the layout*/
    webcamPanel = new JPanel();
    webcamPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout()); 
    webcamPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(550, 480));
    webcamPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));

    /*Place the components*/
    webcamPanel.setVisible(true);
    webcamPanel.add(liveStream, BorderLayout.NORTH);        
    webcamPanel.add(mediaPlayerComponent, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    this.setVisible(true); 

    try{
        mediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPlayer().playMedia("http://127.0.0.1:8989/movie");
    }catch(IllegalStateException e){
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
}
```

Then, of course, the WebcamPanel is added to the current JFrame.

What did I do wrong ?

This is the output : `The video surface component must be displayable`
Thanks to those who will respond !

Ps : Here are the subject I checked : 
- https://github.com/caprica/vlcj/issues/29 
- [Failed to play video by vlcj in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16023836/failed-to-play-video-by-vlcj-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually say precisely what is not working.

On the face of it, it looks like you are missing a layout constraint.

Probably this:

```
webcamPanel.add(canvas);
```

Should be this:

```
webcamPanel.add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Otherwise you are adding your Canvas with a `null` layout constraint.

The "video component must be displayable" error is because you can not play a video until the user interface is displayable - VLC does not have a valid window handle for the Canvas until you either `pack()` the frame, or make it visible. In short, before you play the video you should do `frame.setVisible(true)`.

In relation to threading, the usual Swing threading rules apply - i.e. you must ensure that changes to UI components are invoked on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). Normally you don't need worry about this, like when you respond to a Swing event listener. You only need to worry about this if you have a background thread (not the Swing EDT) that initiates the creation or manipulation of Swing components. If you need to do this, you use `invokeLater` on the `SwingUtilities` class. I don't think this is needed in your case, but without more code it's hard to say.

A slightly off-topic but related comment: with modern versions of vlcj, there are much easier ways to do this, e.g. by using `EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent` it takes care of the media player, the video surface and the associated `Canvas` for you. You just add the component to your layout and you're done.

Comment: Thank you for the answer ! I updated my question to bre more accurate and I now use an EmbeddedMediaPlayer. Still, I have this output : The video surface component must be displayable. Do you know what does it mean ?

Comment: Thank you yor the help you give me ! I edited the question so that the code is what I have now. I set the frame visible before trying to play the stream but I still have the same error. I don't know why ...