# Error importing windowscanvas

Tags: java, video, canvas, import, vlcj

Hi I am developing a quiz application. For playing audio/video I use vlcj player. I've always displayed the video/audio in a separate `JFrame`, but now I would like to place it in a `jpanel` and add it to a `Jframe` where the question is already displayed.

I've found a post in here where someone tries to do this:   [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10609338/trying-to-embed-vlcj-media-player-in-a-windowscanvas-inside-a-jpanel)

But when i copy and use this code i get an error with importing this line:

```
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.runtime.windows.WindowsCanvas;
```

All the other things are imported well.
I am using : `jna -3.5.2`, platform `-3.5.2`, `vlcj- 3.0.1`

Anybody knows whats wrong?
Am I using a wrong version?

Thanks ahead !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WindowsCanvas` was present in old versions of vlcj but is now obsolete.

It used to be needed to get keyboard and mouse events from the native video surface propagated to the Java application, while video was playing,

This `WindowCanvas` used an installation of a native global mouse/keyboard event hook on Windows - which was never an optimal solution - and could cause a fatal JVM crash when your application exited.

With contemporary versions of vlcj and VLC, this is no longer required and so has been removed.

Additionally, the Javadoc for `EmbeddedMediaPlayer` in vlcj states:

> Note that to get mouse and keyboard events delivered via listeners on
>   some platforms (i.e. Windows) you will likely need to invoke
>   setEnableMouseInputHandling(boolean) and setEnableKeyInputHandling(boolean)}

Comment: Oh ok, thanks. Is there any way that i can display it in a jpanel now or not?

Comment: You have to use a heavyweight component, i.e. Canvas. But you can put your Canvas inside a JPanel of course.